# Check if all elements of one array exist in other

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering if there is a PHP function that can check if all the values of one array exist in another.

So for example i have this:

```
$a = array ('v1', 'v3', 'v4');
$b = array ('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5');
```

I want to compare `$a` with `$b`. And since all values of `$a` also exist in `$b` it should return `true`.

Is there an efficient way of doing this in PHP?

Comment: Oh how I love the smell of nice people in the morning.

Comment: Here you ask for help not for development for you.

Comment: This is a trivial task commonly handled by all developers.  If your looking for the most efficient way to do this, please reword your question.  Otherwise, as u_mulder mentioned, you need to some more reading on PHP.

Comment: @Coelho Development? It's giving the name of one function. Which isn't such a weird question at all. It's easy to get lost in the large array of oddly named PHP functions.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=php+compare+array+value+in+other+array&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=9HN_Ut-mIsfE4APN04GICg#q=php+compare+array+value+in+another+array&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&spell=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[First way](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZIOyqP):

```
$result = $a === array_intersect($a, $b);
```

[Second way](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0WVq3J):

```
$result = !count(array_diff($a, $b));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_diff`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). It returns all elements of the first array that do not exist in the second. If the result is empty, all items will exist in the other array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$a = array('v1', 'v3', 'v4');
$b = array('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5');

function is_array_in_array($a, $b) {
    return count($a) === count(array_intersect($a, $b));
}

$test = is_array_in_array($a, $b);

var_dump($test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array ('v1', 'v3', 'v4');
$b = array ('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5');

function compare($first,$second) {
    return count(array_diff($first, $second))==0;
}

compare($a,$b); // true
```

---

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done by using:

```
$result = $a === array_intersect($a, $b);
```